# msvbvm60.dll deployment on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: deployment, vb6

I created an installer using the VB6 Package and Deployment Wizard and stared testing on both Windows 10 32bit and Windows 10 64bit. The apps seen to behave as expected. Development environment includes SP6. I'm a little concerned about the deployment of msvbvm60.dll on the 64bit version. The setup program version is 6.0.98.48 but it is not getting copied to SysWOW64. The existing version, 6.0.98.15, does not get updated. When I look at ST6UNST.LOG I see this:

*ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\msvbvm60.dll"
(File was not found or was an older version -- new file copied)*

The other files, e.g., MSCOMM32.OCX, get copied to SysWOW64 and registered.

This does not happen on Windows 10 32Bit, The updated msvbvm60.dll exists in windows\system32.

Anyone understand what's going on here?

Comment: I've been having a similar problem with the installer (the PDW) not copying some ancillary filers when doing an update (configuration files, text files for localization, etc.)  All of the executables get replaced with newer version as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your install ought to deploy `msvbvm60.dll`. It is [shipped as part of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy?redirectedfrom=MSDN#runtime-files-supported-and-shipping-in-windows) so I think you should leave it be.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy?redirectedfrom=MSDN#supported-runtime-files-to-distribute-with-your-application) the list of files you *can* redistribute, if you need them.

The Package and Deployment Wizard was probably created before the VB6 runtime was adopted into Windows. I am not sure how you edit the installer to prevent it from installing that file.